# Can I make Corn Dogs in advance?

Tags: freezing, corn, hot-dog

I have about 100 people who will be coming over for a carnival. We wanted to make corn dogs, I made them for the Super Bowl to test it and 16 took me close to 1.5 hours. At that rate, in the 4 house we will be making the party I will have a lot of disappointed people. I need about 150. 
I used this recipe http://allrecipes.com/recipe/corn-dogs/ is was very good. What if I make the in advance and freeze them, then defrost them the day before and pop them back into the frier for taste and to warm them up at the party?

Answer (score 2):

You can make them ahead of time, you can partially fry them after dipping them in the batter and frying them until they are a light golden color (enough the batter wont stick to each other). As you complete them, put them in the freezer and when ready just pop them in the hot oil (defrosted of course.) This will not only let you get them ready to go ahead of time but will also shave off time in between serving each corn dog. As with anything before serving to a large group though, test it ahead of time to make sure nothing funky happens.

Also, what kind of fryer do you have, it may very well be the culprit here if you are not using a restaurant quality one. If you aren't, there are a couple of decent options. Let me know what you are using, and I will get back to you on what you can do instead.